# Access a dictionary (JSON format) in a function with a flexible variable

Tags: swift, dictionary

I can't find a solution for my programming issue. I want to create a function which will access a dictionary (data is coming from the internet) an I need the following code very often:

```
if let job_dict = json["data"] as? [String:Any] {
```

It would be great to be more flexible and to change the ["data"] part to a variable or something like that:

```
func get_JSON(Link: String, Value: String) -> [Double] {
    let url = Link
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    let myUrl = URL(string: basePath)!
    var ValuestoReturn = [Double]()

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: myUrl) { (data, response, error) in
        if let data = data {
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [String:Any] {
                    print(Value.description)
                    if let job_dict = json[Value.description] as? [String:Any] {
                        print(job_dict)
                    }
                }
            } catch {
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
```

`json[Value.description]` is always wrong and the `json["data"]` thing is always true.

Comment: What do you mean by "always wrong"?

Comment: the if let job_dict = json[Value.description] as? [String:Any] { is always "false"

Comment: @kabal00 What is printed by `print(Value.Description)`?

Comment: this command shows "data" in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Value.Description use just **Value**

```
print(Value)
if let job_dict = json[Value] as? [String:Any] {...}
```

P.D: Don't use "Value" for a variable's name. The first letter in uppercase is for types. You can use **value** instead.

Comment: thanks for the answer. This doesn't work for me. The if clause is always false.

Comment: what is the value of Value? Do you can show your json response?

Comment: The value of Value is "data". When I put json["data"] in the brackets the if clause will be true and the data will be printed... 
I could post the json data here but it is a bit long.

Comment: How do you call "get_JSON"? `get_JSON(Link: "YourLink", Value: "data")`?

Comment: I saw your previous comment _"data" will be initialized with get_JSON(Value: "\"data\"")_. "\"data\"" is different than "data".

Comment: Wow, that right. Thanks for this very easy solution. I was not able to find this by myself. I thought I have to search for "data" with double quotations. But you only need to search for the string data. Thanks again, now a can finalize my code